# Date-fns format function shows next date instead of the expected one

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I was trying to format a date from ISO using **date-fns** library and it's giving the next day as the output.

```
format(new Date("2021-03-16T23:42:37Z"), "MMM do"); 
// Output: Mar 17th
```

I am expecting to get Mar 16. Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong in here?

Comment: If you remove `Z` and then parse it, it will show 16 march. just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing ‘Z’ is UTC but the Date instance gets created in your local time zone. 23:42 in UTC is after midnight where you are.